# Using OSGi and Apache Felix iPOJO with JDK 11

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix, ipojo

I have a project that is built around OSGi and iPOJO and I'm trying to determine if it will still work with JDK 11. It's currently using JDK 8. It's not looking too hopeful since the latest version of iPOJO (1.12.1) was released in 2014. After updating the target and maven compiler version, I'm running into the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle (default) on project redacted: Execution default of goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle failed. IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle (default) on project redacted: Execution default of goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.model.parser.AnnotationParser.read(AnnotationParser.java:32)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.registry.MetaAnnotationBindingRegistry.createBindings(MetaAnnotationBindingRegistry.java:94)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.registry.CompletableBindingRegistry.getBindings(CompletableBindingRegistry.java:45)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.registry.CompletableBindingRegistry.getBindings(CompletableBindingRegistry.java:43)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.registry.CompletableBindingRegistry.getBindings(CompletableBindingRegistry.java:43)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.registry.Selection.list(Selection.java:129)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.registry.Selection.get(Selection.java:98)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.annotation.MethodMetadataCollector.visitAnnotation(MethodMetadataCollector.java:69)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider.computeAnnotations(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:111)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider.access$200(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:44)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider$1.visit(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:90)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.store.JarFileResourceStore.accept(JarFileResourceStore.java:161)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.AnnotationMetadataProvider.getMetadatas(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:75)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.metadata.CompositeMetadataProvider.getMetadatas(CompositeMetadataProvider.java:53)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.Pojoization.pojoization(Pojoization.java:360)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.manipulator.Pojoization.pojoization(Pojoization.java:243)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.plugin.ManipulatorMojo.execute(ManipulatorMojo.java:265)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
```

From a cursory glance, it looks like the asm dependency of the maven-ipojo-plugin is having trouble with JDK 11, which would make sense because iPOJO has a transitive dependency on asm 5.0.4, and JDK 11 support was not added until asm 7.0. I tried to exclude the transitive dependency and added asm 7.0 as a dependency, but I still get the same error.

Thanks for looking, I'd appreciate any other ideas to try or insights.

Comment: The plugin must use the asm library for JDK 11 (the class file format has changed). Most likely, it will require an update of the plugin, but in some cases it has helped to specify the version of asm directly in the plugin. Inside the 'plugin' element for  'maven-ipojo-plugi' in pom.xml, you can specify 'dependencies'->'dependency' . The dependency has groupId:org.ow2.asm, artifactId:asm, version:7.0

Comment: Thanks for doing that! Specifying  so changed the error to: `Execution default of goal org.apache.felix:maven-ipojo-plugin:1.12.1:ipojo-bundle failed: This feature requires ASM7` which is odd, since I'm trying to require asm 7. Any ideas about that one?

Comment: It means that the plugin must be updated. I've seen the same issue for maven-shade-plugin and maven-plugin-plugin. Sorry, but if the plugin is not maintained, you'll have to think of an alternative to the ipojo-plugin in order to migrate to Java 11.

Comment: That's too bad. That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @gjoranv Could you post your reply as an answer? I will accept it to protect this answer for future googlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IllegalArgumentException` from [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/index.html) during a maven build indicates that a plugin is using a version of the ASM library that is too old for the current Java bytecode. Java 11 bytecode requires ASM 7 (as you mention), which was only released in a stable version a few weeks ago.

When migrating from JDK 9 to 10, it was possible to work around this by explicitly declaring ASM 6.2 as a dependency to e.g. maven-shade-plugin:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- TODO: Remove for shade-plugin 3.1.2 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-289 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <version>6.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

This trick has not worked for JDK 11, which has required updates in the plugins themselves, e.g. `maven-shade-plugin` and `maven-plugin-plugin`. As shown by your efforts, the same goes for `maven-ipojo-plugin`. If the plugin is not maintained, you should probably think of an alternative to the ipojo-plugin in order to migrate to Java 11.

You could try to set the `target` version to 1.8 for the `maven-compiler-plugin`, which should have the effect that the class files will be compatible with the ipojo-plugin. But then you probably have to set the `source` version to 1.8 as well, and won't be able to use any Java 9+ language features.